# How to delete everything except .svn directories?

Tags: find, pattern-matching

I have quite complex directory tree. There are many subdirectories, in those subdirectories beside other files and directories are ".svn" directories.

Now, under linux I want to delete all files and directories **except** the .svn directories.

I found many solutions about opposite behaviour - deleting all .svn directories in the tree. Can somebody quote me the correct answer for deleting everything except .svn?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I usually use a relatively simple `find` with the `-exec` option, as I always forget about the -delete command.  I also restrict to files-only.  Mostly because I use some variation of `find {someswitches} -exec {somecommand}` a lot - so I remember it!

`find . -type f -not path '*.svn*' -exec rm {} \;`

Comment: Using ubuntu I had to add a `-` before the `path` like this: `find . -type f -not -path '*.svn*' -exec rm {} \;`

Answer (score 1):

**Untested:** `find . -not -path '*.svn*'`... if those are all the files you want to clobber, run it again with the `-delete` option.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `rm -rf -- $(ls -la |grep -v .svn)`. It will remove everything (including hidden files) except the `.svn` dir.

*EDIT*: The above solution works for one dir, not a tree, `find . ! -name .svn -exec rm {} \;` will remove all FILES and not the dirs. It's a safe way to do that, since if you force the `rm` on directories you can delete directories that have `.svn` directories inside.

Comment: Sorry. I can't parse your last sentence. What do you mean by *"if you force the rm on directories you can delete directories that have .svn directories inside."*

Comment: Suppose you have a dir called x that has a .svn dir inside, if you use rm -rf you can end removing x and all it's child directories, thus removing the .svn subdir in the process.

Comment: I tried your second command (without the -exec) and it deletes all the files in the .svn folders too.  I think what Arek wants is to keep all the stuff _in_ the .svn folders too, not just empty folders.  You also get all sorts of errors about trying to delete directories.